# Test iPhone app in real device

Tags: ios

I have an apple developer ID. I have my developer certificate, my cert in my keychain, I have installed the last version of iOS (5.1.1 (9B206)) in my device (an iPad), I got my profile, I'm on a development team, I told Xcode that I want to use the device for testing. In the build settings, I have set the architectures to armv6 and armv7, both in "target" and "project" as well. Got the provisioning profile.

Still, when I try to run the app on the iPad, I receive an "Xcode cannot run using the selected device." saying that I need to install a newer iOS version (as I said, I installed the most recent on the device).

Anyone have faced this issue before?

Comment: what is the version of xcode?

Comment: Is the device enlisted as a test device for the application that you are trying to install?

Comment: The version is Xcode 4.3

Comment: In the scheme menu at the top left of xCode, does it say iOS device, or does it actually have the name of your device?

Comment: lawicko, when i go to the organizer, the device is there. I click the "use for testing" button.

Comment: I didn't mean the organizer, you need to make sure that the application you are trying to test can be run on this device. Go to your developer account and check if this device is in the provisioning profile for your application.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but you are mean the account in the apple page? The provisioning profile has the unique ID of the device for what it's created, i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to update the version of Xcode to `4.3.2`

Comment: In Xcode->Preferences->Downloads->check and install now button, it says "No updates available".

Comment: Yes. This computer is in the office i work in, we do everything legal :P

Comment: Version 4.3 (4E109) this is the version of the XCode.

Comment: You need to download the 4.3.2 update from the Mac App Store or from the iOS Developer Center.

Comment: You mean uninstalling the XCode i have and reinstall it? Since there is no "update file", or at least i can't find it.

Comment: dont uninistall the one you have, you can have more than 1 xcode version on your machine, but yes install the latest one from the appstore

Comment: Hmm that seems to be the problem. But, the account that installed XCode in the Mac is not my account... and the guy who installed the XCode doesn't work here anymore, and the App Store asks me for that account...but I have a hint, at last. Thank you all for your help, guys.